# what does it mean that "event" is deprecated in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate an email form with jQuery, and it isn't working, here is the part of the code I think the problem is:

```
if (isValid == false) {
        event.preventDefault();                
    }
```

I get the message that event is deprecated, what does this mean and how can I fix it?

EDIT (here's the whole code):

```
$("#contact_form").submit( evt => {
     let isValid = true;

  // validate the first name entry
    const firstName = $("#first_name").val().trim();
    if (firstName == "") {
      $("#first_name").next().text("This field is required.");
      isValid = false;
    } else {
      $("#first_name").next().text("");
    }
    $("#first_name").val(firstName);

  // validate the last name entry
  const lastName = $("#last_name").val().trim();
  if (lastName == "") {
      $("#last_name").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
      $("#last_name").next().text("");
  }
  $("#last_name").val(lastName);

// validate the email entry with a regular expression
    const emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
    const email = $("#email").val().trim();
        if (email == "") { 
            $("#email").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else if ( !emailPattern.test(email) ) {
         $("#email").next().text("Must be a valid email address.");
         isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#email").next().text("");
        }
         $("#email").val(email);
    
    // validate the verify entry
    const verify = $("#verify").val().trim();
    if (verify == "") { 
        $("#verify").next().text("This field is required.");
        isValid = false; 
    } else if (verify !== email) { 
        $("#verify").next().text("Must match first email entry.");
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        $("#verify").next().text("");
    }
    $("#verify").val(verify);
  
                
    // prevent the submission of the form if any entries are invalid 
    if (isValid == false) {
        event.preventDefault();                
    }
}),
```

Comment: Do you have any additional code? What is the listener that is triggering this event? Is the message you're receiving in the browser console?

Comment: yes, I can provide the rest of it, I was coding in vs code

Comment: There's not really enough code here for context, but I assume it's referring to the [event global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), which indeed shouldn't be used, for reasons that have nothing whatsoever to do with jQuery.

Comment: thanks! I'm really new to this, what should I use instead of "event"?

Comment: You should probably use the `evt` argument which is passed into your event handler here `$("#contact_form").submit( evt => {`.

Comment: Probably `evt`, like you're passing at the top of your function: `$("#contact_form").submit( evt => {`, so `evt.preventDefault()`

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot I changed that when trying to fix it, also what do you mean exactly? @takendarkk

Comment: Stop using `event` and instead use `evt`. They are 2 different things.

Comment: thanks I changed it, but the code still isn't working, I'm very frusterated, does anyone have any suggestions? thank you again for the help

Comment: @iglified if its the same error, provide us with the exact text of the error. If its a different error, that would warrant posting a new question.

Comment: For clarity, just in case: `evt` is only called `evt` because that's what you named it in the function argument. People typically use 'e' or 'evt' in event handlers, but it could be named anything.  The global `window.event` is what's deprecated and should be avoided.

Comment: okay, I understand, I'm new to here

Answer (score 0):

Change event to evt.

```
if (!isValid) 
{
    evt.preventDefault();                
}
```

The event you're trying to prevent is the one from the 'submit' listener. Not the global event.

```
$("#contact_form").submit( evt => { });
```